# ActionBar V7: Why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to include the ActionBar V7 in my application. In AndroidManifest.xml i put

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

In values/style.xml

```
    <resources>

        <!--
            Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
            by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
        -->
        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!--
                Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
                res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
                backward-compatibility can go here.
            -->

    </style>
        <!-- Application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

            <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        </style>

</resources>
```

In values-v11

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<resources>
<!-- Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices. -->
-<style parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" name="AppBaseTheme">
<!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style></resources>
```

And in values-v14

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

In the Activitys i put

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

Upon execution tells me that there are errors in the project. Precisely the errors are in all style.xml and the error is "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
" Why i have this error and how i fix it? I put the library android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in /libs and right click to add it to Build Patch. I also tried to restart eclipse but it does not work the same.

Comment: Did you read how you need to setup the library http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html ?

Comment: Use `@Theme.AppCompat.Light` not `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. You forgot to add `@` in front of theme's name.

Answer (score 1):

The v7 appcompat library includes resources in addition to the JAR file. Instructions for including libraries with resources can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

Adding libraries with resources - Using Eclipse